# Change the Position of Jquery Mobile Range Slider values field

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am using this code for jquery mobile range slider plugin.

```
<div class="ui-field-contain">
  <div data-role="rangeslider">
    <label for="range-7a">Rangeslider:</label>
    <input name="range-7a" id="range-7a" min="0" max="100" value="0" type="range" />
    <label for="range-7b">Rangeslider:</label>
    <input name="range-7b" id="range-7b" min="0" max="100" value="100" type="range" />
  </div>
</div>
```

the result will display values at the both end of the slider.Is their any way to place the range values on top of the slider like[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The css for those inputs with the numbers is `input.ui-slider-input`. However its better if you hide the original ones and record the values to display in a separate div.

**Demo A**

https://jsfiddle.net/fvbyh3hh/

**CSS**

```
input.ui-slider-input {
float: none !important; 
margin-left: 23%;
display:inline-block !important;
}
```

**Demo B**

https://jsfiddle.net/aeg0p5kw/

**HTML addition**

```
<div class='range1'>0 - 100</div>
```

**Css**

```
input.ui-slider-input {
display:none !important;
}

.range1 {
margin-left:55%;
color:red;
}
```

**Jquery**

```
var vala, valb;
$(document).on("change", "#range-7a, #range-7b", function(){ 
vala = $("#range-7a").val();
valb = $("#range-7b").val();
$(".range1").text(vala+" - "+valb);  
})
```